# Installation Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS gets stuck on Synology Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, nas

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS on a virtual machine on my Synology NAS 718+ (Intel Celeron J3455 and 10GB RAM).
(Virtual Machine Manager with a VM setting of 2 CPUs, 4GB RAM, and 50GB Storage)

The machine starts booting and I get to a menu saying either to "Test / Install Unbuntu" OR "Test Memory" after confirming to install a lot of commands are passing by but even after 2 hours nothing more happened.

I tried installing the following Ubuntu versions without issues with the same VM settings:

- Ubuntu Server 20.04
- Ubuntu Desktop 22.04(!)

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue on DS218+ with 10GB Ram. I set the display driver to VGA from Virt_VGA and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you very much it was as easy as that. Now it works.

Comment: Just came here to say, its 2024 and this is still the answer.